# Change the order of icons in the Launcher in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

I have a column of program shortcuts on the Launcher in Ubuntu. How can I change the order of the icons?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on icon and hold mouse button down for 2 seconds, then move it.

Answer (score 2):

Use your mouse left click to select and hold it. After hold take it out and continue holding then arrange or replace at place you want.

Don't leave holding mouse until you place it where ever you want.